# Is there a brief overview of fine structure theory of inner models for a relatively general audience?

Tags: reference-request, set-theory

There are quite a few articles about forcing (such as http://www-math.mit.edu/~tchow/forcing.pdf) which give a large picture overview appropriate for someone with nothing more than an introductory graduate course in set theory.  I was wondering if there was anything equivalent for the fine structure theory of L and other inner models?  I know about the handbook of set theory articles but these presupposes a technical background knowledge of inner model theory.

Comment: The background needed for fine structure theory of $L$ itself is not that much (and that's your place to start anyway). Jensen's original article doesn't have too many prerequisites. If you want a more modern (and more general) treatment, take a look at the handbook article by Schindler and Zeman. Both of the articles end up proving the same results about $L$.
Or do you want an overview article about inner model theory itself?

Comment: So I have a copy of Zeman's book and the Jensen article, I was wondering if anyone had written a broad overview article so I could have an idea of why certain techniques were important.

Comment: I still don't know whether you're talking about fine structure or inner model theory. I'm not sure how many techniques there are in fine structure, in some sense you could consider it a technique itself.

Comment: I'm probably just revealing my ignorance, the question was about fine structure.  The suggestion then is just to look at Jensen's original article?

Comment: Yes, or the handbook article, which is available from Martin Zeman's website (http://www.math.uci.edu/~mzeman/RESEARCH/index.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lot of the material from the Handbook chapter (at least concerning $L$) is also covered in Ralf Schindler's book *Set Theory: Exploring Independence and Truth*, with the added benefit that more details are worked out and the book covers all the prerequisites. For a fancier treatment that covers more complicated inner models (and also does things like $\Sigma^*$ theory) perhaps Zeman's *Inner Models and Large Cardinals* might work.